# ActionBar (Sherlock) displaying icon with number of messages on top

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am working with ActionBar and since I have Messaging functionality I wanted to notify user in ActionBar if he has any unread messages. It would look kinda like this:

[image: Messages unread - example notification]

However, I can't seem to find if this is supported. So, does anyone know if this is supported and how I would add an icon over existing ActionBar item in this fashion?

Comment: Did you happen to get this up and running and if so would you be willing to update us with a snippet w. what you ended up doing?

Comment: @ChuckKelly In the end I just used Text portion of ActionBar item to display number of new messages. If there are none I just put "" String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach to this would be to create a modified drawable yourself and set it as the source of that particular ActionBar icon. To do this you can call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` and re-set the icon from within `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)`. You can use a [`LayerDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) to superimpose the number on top of your actual icon drawable.

Comment: You can also place any arbitrary view in the action bar using `setDisplayOptions(DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM)` and `setCustomView(view)`

Comment: If you're going with `setCustomView(view)`, just subclass ImageView and in the `onDraw()` method, paint the desired number onto the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

I do  not think it is something built-in in the API, however there is a simple implementation for a [badge-button](https://github.com/jcxavier/badge-button) that might help you